# Фильтры Firebase бросают непонятную мне ошибку

Tags: android, firebase-database, firebase-android

Этот код:

```
var query: Query = store.collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", filter.startAge).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("age", filter.endAge)
query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("start_date", filter.startDate).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("end_date", filter.endDate)
query = query.whereEqualTo("sex", filter.sex)
return query.get()
```

бросает ошибку:                                                                      `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'age' and 'start_date'`
как исправть?

Comment: В Firebase нельзя делать множественные фильтры. Есть два варианта: либо получать все данные и фильтровать их на устройстве, либо делать комбинированные поля.

Comment: @ahgpoug как сделать комбинированые поля?

Comment: вариант с фильтрацией на локальной машине, начальнику не очень понравился

Comment: я не могу утверждать, что решения в данном случае нет, но с `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo`, боюсь, вариантов нет. Если бы было `whereEqualTo`, то можно просто запихнуть два свойства в одно поле. А так - только брать результаты по первому фильтру и делать вторую фильтрацию вручную.

Comment: @ahgpoug я об этом так-же думал,  но полагал, что есть более изящное решение. В любом случае, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не слишком много элементов в БД, то фильтровать на локальной машине, а в обратном случае фильтровать со стартового параметра, а в пришедшем запросе фильтровать по конечному варианту.